# How to make an ExtJS recursive template to output any javascript object?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I was watching the following video and wondered if it was possible to make a recursive template to output all the properties/method names of any object in the DOM?  --
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/docs/index.html#!/video/17905336

Here is a pure javascript example of what I'm curious about doing with an XTemplate in extjs  --  http://jsfiddle.net/SLJZ3/

```
var mObj = {};
mObj.mArr = [];
mObj.mArr.push({id:['id1','id2','id3']});
mObj.mArr.push({days:['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday']});
mObj.mArr.push({colors:['orange','red','blue','green','yellow','white']});
mObj.mArr.push(function isTrue(){return true;});

function r(obj) {
    if (obj)
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (typeof obj[key] == "object")
                r(obj[key]);
            else if (typeof obj[key] == "function")
              document.writeln("<span style='color:silver'>" + obj[key] + "</span><br/>");
            else if (typeof obj[key] != "function")
                document.writeln(obj[key] + "<br/>")
        }

    return;
} 

r(mObj);​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XTemplate](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate) allows executing custom functions or even arbitrary inline code inside templates (see appropriate sections in the linked docs page) so I guess technically you can call a recursive function from within XTemplate but that would be no better than just calling your recursive function directly.

I see your idea here - bringing markup outside of your output function but I'm afraid XTemplate won't be very helpful if you want to iterate an **object**, because it only has constructs for iterating **arrays**.

The example in "Auto filling of arrays" says:

```
<tpl for=".">...</tpl>       // loop through array at root node
```

So you can only write a template like this:

```
<p>Name: {name}</p>
<tpl for="days">
    ...iterate days array
</tpl>
<tpl for="colors">
    ...iterate colors array
</tpl>
```

That is when you know what properties should be there inside your data object.

Or you can define separate templates for different types of data you output.

Comment: thanks for the additional info.  i guess i would need to first recursively push the DOM element into a tree that could then be used in a tpl?

Comment: you mean recursively iterate your data to create a template on the fly and then actually apply it on the fly? That sounds like an overkill, useful only if the structure of your data repeats. but if it repeats then your could create your template statically?